# Stop code execution if file is missing

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I use this code in order to load configuration file.

```
def load_environment_config(gateway, trx_type)
  @config = YAML.load_file("config/#{env}_config.yml")["#{env.upcase}"]
  puts "\nMissing gateway configuration for #{gateway} in file config/#{env}_config.yml!\n\n" unless @config[gateway]
end
```

How I can stop code execution if line in file configuration is missing?

Comment: @Stefan message is printed and code execution continues.

Comment: What do you mean by "stop code execution"? Raising an exception?

Comment: @Stefan yes, and print some message.

Comment: Use [`raise`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Kernel.html#method-i-raise) 
 (or its alias `fail`) instead of `puts`.

Comment: @Stefan Can you show me complete code example please?

Comment: BTW, if `env` returns a symbol, you should use `env.to_s.upcase` instead of `"#{env.upcase}"`. Or simply `env.upcase` if `env` already returns a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`raise`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Kernel.html#method-i-raise) an exception:

```
def load_environment_config(gateway, trx_type)
  @config = YAML.load_file("config/#{env}_config.yml")[env.to_s.upcase]
  raise "Missing ..." unless @config[gateway]
end
```

Which will stop execution if it is not rescued, usually printing the error message and its backtrace.

You can also use your own [`Exception`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Exception.html) class:

```
class ConfigurationError < StandardError; end

def load_environment_config(gateway, trx_type)
  @config = YAML.load_file("config/#{env}_config.yml")[env.to_s.upcase]
  raise ConfigurationError, "Missing ..." unless @config[gateway]
end
```